# How to harden a chocolate made from Regular (unsalted) butter?

Tags: chocolate

I am trying to make chocolate in following steps-

Take cocoa powder (unsweetened) and powdered sugar. Grind them. Add Regular (unsalted) melted butter, mix them for long. And pour them in moulds.

But the chocolate does not settle, even after keeping it in a refrigerator. Tempering will not help, as it works only for chocolate made with cocoa butter.

What steps I must do to get a chocolate that settles?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a chocolate truffle recipe rather than actual chocolate. Truffles are normally soft

Comment: @ChrisH So what steps can I add to make it a chocolate. And Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: You may want to look at [this related question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/66936/making-dark-chocolate-at-home).

Comment: If what you're trying to make is chocolate, then the link @Stephie gave will tell you what you need to know (if not what you want to know).  If you want to make some other form of chocolatey goodness that might be doable, but not based on butter

Comment: I myself found a related question on post shared by @Stephie, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/36645/68444 . Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to make chocolate at home, but you'd need a chocolate-friendly model of a tabletop wet grinder to use for conching.  Not something for casual use, though.  I've some descriptions and links in this answer [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/50276/how-do-i-use-cacao-nibs-in-the-chocolate-making-recipe/73612#73612)

Comment: @Megha Conching will not solve my problem as I want a harder chocolate rather than softer chocolate, which is the result of conching.( I will now try to replace regular buttter with some kind of oil or other type of butter.)

Comment: @TontyTon - sorry, I wasn't clear, my comment probably should've been under rumtscho's answer.  What I meant was the links for info on making proper chocolate, using cocoa butter instead of butter, since cocoa butter does give a hard chocolate, but that would need conching to smooth the result or it would be gritty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done. Chocolate has the hardness of chocolate, because it is made out of cocoa butter. Dairy butter is not suitable for that. There are industrial processes which use hydrogenated plant fat and emulsifiers to make chocolate bars with a somewhat different texture than pure chocolate, but still hard - I doubt that you can do that without industrial grade equipment.

For all practical purposes, what you are trying to do is impossible.

Comment: Making hard butter is easy. You just have to freeze it. :)

Answer (score 2):

The snap of chocolate comes from one specific crystallization of cocoa butter, out of six forms. Getting that specific form requires careful temperature control.

That form is particular to cocoa butter. You won't be able to make it other fats. Especially not whole butter, which is a complicated mixture of various kinds of fatty acids with proteins and water.

You might get a slightly harder compound if you start with clarified butter or ghee, but it's never going to have the distinctive snap of cocoa butter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try with it even?

Comment: Good luck, and let us know. I think at best you might get the texture of a Hershey bar, which I guess some people like.